# Python Syntax offer

Tags: python

```
name = input('Enter your name') 
age = int(intt('Enter your age')) 
if name == 'Amrit': 
    print('Hello ' +name) 
if age == 26: 
    print('Your age is ' +age) 
else('Hello Strenger') 
else('Hello Strenger')

error --> unexpected indent
```

Comment: Use ` to format your code. For now this is impossible to help you...

Comment: why are you calling `else`. can you clarify what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to input name as Amrit and age 26, if user entered correct, then only display the correct output else got to else statement...plese help

Comment: You can also use a linter that will display the syntax errors that you make in python (most IDE come with one, you just need to activate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `and` with `if` statement for checking multiple conditions.

```
name = input('Enter your name') 
age = int(input('Enter your age')) 

if name == 'Amrit' and age == 26: 
    print('Hello ' +name) 
else:
    print('Hello Strenger')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
name = input('Enter your name') 
age = int(input('Enter your age')) 
if name == 'Amrit' and age==26: 
    print('Hello ' +name) 
    print('Your age is ' ,age) 
else:
    print('Hello Stranger')
```